# Nginx and php-fpm communication issue

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have 2 nginx server and 4 dedicated php-fpm servers configured in upstream for executing PHP with 2 instances each means in upstream i have given 8 instances with ports 9000 & 9001 for each php-fpm server.

Sometime what happens nginx not able to connect php-fpm on port 9000 and 9001 and even when i do telnet from nginx to php-fpm server on port 9000 or 9001 it does not connect.

What kind of log should be enabled on nginx and php-fpm to identify the issue weather its a network connectivity issue or server issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do a traceroute to make sure you are able to reach the remote php-fpm servers from nginx servers.  Also, are these servers in the same LAN or is it on different networks, or is it going via Internet ?

Comment: they are on same LAN and same IP series. Is there any recommended way for traceroute??

Comment: Just look for it on Google. traceroute is straight-forward command. 
Usually you diagnose path from your end to remote end. 
So, do a trace from the machine that wants to connect the other. You can do both ways to make sure that both machines can communicated with each other. Also, check MAC address for both/three nodes to ensure that IP in question is the same and not a spoof or conflicting one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that php-fpm only listens on 127.0.0.1 en does not accept connections from other servers, you should run (as root) 'netstat -tulnp' and see on what port/address php-fpm listens on.

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply.I check php-fpm IP/port it listens on private ip and on port 9000 & 9001 because i am running two instances on each server one on 9000 and another on 9001

Comment: post the output of  <code>netstat -ntlp |grep -e ':9000\|9001'</code>  from the node running 9000 and the one running 9001

Comment: tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9000          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9001          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      - please check output where xxx.xxx.xx.xx is IP address and i have 4 machines for php-fpm in cluster and each have two instances running on port 9000 and 9001

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, four things come to my mind.

1. Routing - Are the two nodes in a network that makes it able to connect to each other. Use networking tool such as traceroute, arp, arping to check it (arp to ensure the node is the same).
2. Is there a firewall or security policy in between that blocks the said ports.
3. Is your server running RHEL/CentOS/Fedora or any other flavour that enables SELinux ? If yes, you may want to disable that and try. The following commands would give you the status of SElinux and make it permissive if you want it that way. Check status of SElinux: `getenforce` OR `sestatus | grep -i mode`. Make it permissive, if enforcing: `setenforce 0` . Check status again: `getenforce`.
4. check on both servers for IPtables.  `iptables -nL` would list if iptables is enabled and allowing these ports. You can do the following to save current rules, flush it, and stop iptables for the time being.

   ```
   /etc/init.d/iptables save 
   iptables -F 
   /etc/init.d/iptables stop
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Php-fpm may have run out of child processes when this happens, check in your pool logs for errors. This usually happens if you have long running PHP queries in a high traffic environment.

Comment: Hi Simon, When i see top command during that time no php-fpm process shown in top list and load average of system coming in 0.0x so if php-fpm run out of child process then available childs should be visible in top stats.

Comment: Are there processes visible in ps ax at that point as that would point at php-fpm crashing.